# Connecting Android to Windows VPN

Tags: windows, vpn, android, pptp

I have set up a VPN on my Windows 10 computer by going into `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` and hitting `Alt` and then going to `File > New Incoming Connection...` and setting up a `Connect through the internet` connection. I then went into my Comcast router control panel (`10.0.0.1`) and set up a port forward connection that forwards my computer's IP (`10.0.0.2`) at port `1723` type `TCP/UDP` (Although trying just `TCP` didn't work either).

I have the newest version of Android KitKat on my Droid Ultra. I can connect to a VPN in my device's settings. I put in type `PPTP`, server address `xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1723` (My public IP) with PPP encryption (MPPE).

Now that is my whole setup; Except it doesn't work; It says `Connecting...` then `Disconnected` on my phone using my Verizon 4G LTE network. So what did I do wrong?

PS: I am doing this so I can connect to this VPN and then I can use ES File Explorer's LAN explorer to stream my movies to my phone over the internet.